# How to control new pop up tab from VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

i wrote a code that is automatically downloading some documentation if some criterias are met and I just have one problem.. After clicking on a link a new IE tab is opened (child tab) and i would like to close it after some actions. The new tab has always the same title (for example "online.xxx") so maybe there is a way to control it.

My parent tab is setted like this:

```
Dim IE as New ShDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the the Shell Windows to loop through the IE Tabs, then find the special tab based on the title. More detail information, please check the following code:

```
Sub TestClose()
    Dim IE As Object, Data As Object
    Dim ticket As String
    Dim my_url As String, my_title As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://amazon.com" '1st tab
        .Navigate "https://flipkart.com", CLng(2048) '2nd
        .Navigate "https://snapdeal.com", CLng(2048) '3rd

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        'wait some time to let page load
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count

        'loop through the window and find the tab
        For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
            On Error Resume Next
            'get the location and title
            my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
            my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

            'debug to check the value
            Debug.Print x
            Debug.Print my_title

            'find the special tab based on the title.
            If my_title Like "Amazon" & "*" Then
                Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
                IE.Quit 'call the Quit method to close the tab.
                Exit For   'exit the for loop 
            Else
            End If
        Next

    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The code seems really clear. I will definitely try and let you know!

Comment: It works! Thank you. Is there a way to switch the focus on the tab i found by name? I tried AppActivate but it works only with active tabs.

Comment: I also found this issue (want to switch to the special tab), but not found a good ways to do that. I will research about that, If I get any solution or a work around then I will try to provide you in the future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi there. Just the last question regarding the same topic. If two tabs have the same title, teoretically I should use the location to set mine. But is there a way that if my_title  = "amazon", it ignores the first match and looks for a second?

Answer (score 0):

To close an existing tab:

```
Sub TestClose()

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = GetIEByTitle("K1000 Service Center")
    If Not ie Is Nothing Then
        ie.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

Function to find an open IE tab based on the document title:

```
Function GetIEByTitle(sTitle As String) As Object
    Dim o As Object, rv As Object
    For Each o In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If TypeName(o) = "IWebBrowser2" Then
            If o.document.Title Like "*" & sTitle & "*" Then
                Set rv = o
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next o
    Set GetIEByTitle = rv
End Function
```